# Printing value returned from my code in console app

Tags: c#, return, console-application

I am trying to display the results of a calculation in my console application. So it will be sending this class

```
namespace The_Code_Challenge
{
    class HeatCalculator
    {
        public static decimal ActualHeatRate(decimal TotalHeatInput, decimal ActualNetGeneration, GeneratorType generatorType)
        {
            return TotalHeatInput / ActualNetGeneration;
        }
    }
}
```

to my main

```
namespace The_Code_Challenge
{
    class MyClassCS
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            FileWatch.Initialize();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: how do I refer to it in my `main`? And how do I display my result?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Console.WriteLine()`.

Your class `HeatCalculator` need to be Public.

`HeatCalculator calc = new HeatCalculator();  Console.WriteLine(calc.ActualHeatRate(1,2,generatorType));`

Hope it answer your question.

Comment: That makes sense. Ill see if its the result i am looking for! :D

Comment: No "need to be public" if Program is in the same namespace, otherwise yes or internal, isn't it?

Comment: @Goku This will not compile. Since `ActualHeartRate` is marked as `static`, you cannot access it by an instance reference; you ought to access it through the type name instead. `Console.WriteLine(HeatCalculator.ActualHeatRate(1,2,generatorType));`